# Custom logout is not logging out of session completly in Salesforce Community

Tags: community

I have configured a Custom Logout button on the header component on my Community using the below code. Clicking on it, it would then redirect to a page(I call it as Logout screen). But it is not logging out of the session completely. The user session is not killed and I can still access the community from other windows and tabs.

```
<div class="custom-icons-logout">
      <span class="logout_icon">
        <a class="logoutimage" onclick="logout()" role="menuitem" title="Logout">
            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon--cust1" aria-hidden="true" style="">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/support/resource/14/svg/symbols.svg#logout">
              </use>
            </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
</div>

<script>
  logout = function() {
    var win = window.open('https://login.salesforce.com/secur/logout.jsp');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @glls Please help me, how do i achieve the logout functionality instead of redirecting.

Comment: Your URL may not be correct. Not sure if the login url will work as it typically is the site url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a possible duplicate post to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/apex-method-for-logout-from-force-com-site), I didn't really find any documentation and there is a post that mentions this superficially (no concrete example), so here goes.

you will have to redirect the user to the secur/logout.jsp

```
<input type="button" onClick="logOut();" value="custom logout" />
```

and my logout function is a simple redirect using the Site Prefix:

```
  function logOut(){
      window.location.replace("{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp");
  }
```

for those wondering why .jsp:

> JSP is a file extension for Java Server Pages file format. A JSP is an
>   HTML page containing a reference to Java servlets, or, java server
>   side applets.